# Dynamic range compression in the frequency domain?

Tags: fft, audio, dynamic-range-compression

I'm trying to do frequency-band specific dynamic range compression (like multi-band compression) and was thinking of whether dynamic range compression is doable in the frequency domain or whether it's done in the "typical" filtering, gain reduction and then mixing (recombining filtered and GR'ed signals) way using time-domain signals?

Also, what are the benefits/drawbacks over time-domain?

Comment: Are we talking about Images or Audio? Can you tell what are you tryin to achieve?

Comment: I'm trying to do multi-band compression on audio, but the question came about doing it in the frequency domain, if it makes any sense.